# Java: Check auto-generated ID

Tags: java, sql, unique

My Java program adds items into database. I have a code for generating random string that will be used as an item ID. I want to make IDchecker(id) that will check whether the ID already exists into database.

If I have codeIDgenerator() and IDchecker(id) methods, how do I make a loop that will generate new code if the ID already exists, or will exit the loop if the ID is unique and doesn't come up in the database?

Also I'm having trouble with my IDchecker(id) method, I'm using ResultSet to bring back the data from SQL, but I can't find a way to determine how many rows does ResultSet has (if at all). There is no isEmpty() for resultSet?

Here's the code:

```
public void AddItem() {
    boolean checkCode = false;
    while (checkCode == false) {
        Random r = new Random();
        int numbers = 100000 + (int) (r.nextFloat() * 899900);
        String ID= Integer.toString(numbers);
        try {
            if (DatabaseConnection.checkID(ID) == false) {
                checkCode = true;
                System.out.println("ID is unique");
            } else if (DatabaseConnection.checkID(ID) == true) {
                System.out.println("ID is NOT unique");
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ModelTabeleIntervencija.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

And here is the ckeckID(ID) method

```
public boolean CheckID(String ID) throws SQLException {
    String query = "SELECT itemId FROM items WHERE itemID= '"+ID+"'";
    Statement dbStatement = connection.createStatement();
    ResultSet rsItems= dbStatement .executeQuery(query);
        if (rsItems.isEmpty( )== true){
            return false;
            // ID not found - is unique
        } else{
        return true;
            // ID found - is not unique
        }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Most RDBMS implementations have some mechanism for an auto-incrementing column (e.g., `IDENTITY` in SQL Server, `AUTO_INCREMENT` in MySQL). I'd look into that option rather than trying to roll your own solution here.

Comment: Joe is right; no need to re-invent the wheel. Speaking of, you should look into ORMs (e.g. Hibernate) so you don't have to worry about all these cases someone has already thought of and handled.

Comment: I'm a beginner in Java, i don't have a clue what is RDBMS or ORM?  I've just added List that fills up with entries from Result set, with the list.isEmpty() I can easily see if there was any result from the query.

Comment: RDBMS is a relation database. Google will find you millions of pages on it.  This is a feature best done by your database, rather than in Java.

Comment: Yes, I googled it, but RDBSM is a system, I don't know where to begin searching for my problem among billions of results. Anyway, this code of mine works with added ResultList.isEmpty() == true/false. So I'll stick to that.

Comment: @Luka: RDBMS is the DB you're running your SQL queries against.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While generating unique id is best done in your database, I can help you simplify your code.  You shouldn't need to check your database twice.

```
private final Random r = new Random();
public String getUniqueId() {
    try {
        while (true) {
            int n = r.nextInt(1000 * 1000) + 1000 * 1000;
            String id = ("" + n).substring(1); // number between 000000 and 999999
            if (DatabaseConnection.checkID(id))
                return id;
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot access database", ex);
    }
}
```

However, instead of generating a random id, you could just get the next id.

```
public String getUniqueId() {
    try {
        String maxId = DatabaseConnection.selectMaxId();
        int n = Integer.parseInt(maxId) + 1;
        return ("" + n).substring(1); // number between 000000 and 999999
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot access database", ex);
    }
}
```